# manually Set Kendo asp.net mvc grid row to update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

My grid is edited in inline mode.  apparently when kendo doesnt detect a change to d row, the update event will not be fired. i need to cause the update event to fire even when no change has been made on the row because the change will be handled in d controller.

i found this post [Manual row change](http://www.telerik.com/forums/manually-set-grid-row-as-dirty)  but i dont know how to hook that up . im using kendo mvc not the kendo js.

my view

```js
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderViewModel>()
        .Name("orders")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 700px; border: 0;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(t => { })
                .ClientTemplate("#=OrderID#")
                .Title("ORDER ID")
                .Width(120);
            columns.Bound(f => f.OrderDate)
               .Title("ORDER DATE")
               .Format("{0:d}")
               .Width(150);
            columns.Bound(f => f.RequiredDate)
               .Title("REQUIRED DATE")
               .Format("{0:d}")
               .Width(150);
            columns.ForeignKey(f => f.CustomerID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["customers"], "CustomerID", "CompanyName")
                .Title("REQUEST BRANCH")
                .Width(200);
            columns.ForeignKey(f => f.ShipVia, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["shippers"], "ShipperID", "CompanyName")
                .Title("CMU")
                .Width(150); ;
            columns.ForeignKey(f => f.EmployeeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["employees"], "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName")
                .Title("REQUESTED BY")
                .Width(250);
            columns.Bound(f => f.ShipCountry)
                .Title("ORDER STATUS")
                .ClientTemplate("<div class='country #=ShipCountry#'></div>#=ShipCountry#")
                .Width(150);
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit()
                .Text("Approve Order")
                 .UpdateText("Approve")
                 .CancelText("Cancel");

            }).Width(200);
        })
        .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Events(e => e
            .DataBound("onDataBound")
        )
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true))
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Navigatable()
        .Filterable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("Order_DetailTemplate")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.OrderID);
                m.Field(f => f.OrderID).DefaultValue(-42); 
                m.Field(f => f.OrderID).Editable(false);
                m.Field(f => f.OrderDate).Editable(false);
                m.Field(f => f.CustomerID).Editable(false);
                m.Field(f => f.EmployeeID).Editable(false);
                m.Field(f => f.ShipCountry).Editable(false);
                    
                m.Field(f => f.ShipVia).Editable(false);
                    
                
            })
            .Events(e => e.Error(@<text>
                function (e) {
                onError(e, "orders");
                }
            </text>))
                                    .Sort(s => s.Add(f => f.OrderDate).Descending())
                                    .Read("Orders_Read", "Orders")

                                    .Update("Orders_Approve", "Orders")
                                    
                                )
    )
    @{
        Func<object, object> errorEvent = @<text>
            function(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
            onError(e, "order_details#=OrderID#");
            }
            }
        </text>;
    }
    <script id="Order_DetailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <h4>Details for order \\##=OrderID# </h4>
        @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("order_details_tabstrip_#=OrderID#")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add()
                .Text("CURRENCIES")
                .Selected(true)
                .Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderDetailViewModel>()
                    .Name("order_details#=OrderID#")
                    
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.ForeignKey(f => f.ProductID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["products"], "ProductID", "ProductName")
                            .Title("CURRENCY NAME")
                            .EditorTemplateName("CustomGridForeignKey");
                        columns.Bound(f => f.UnitPrice)
                            .Format("{0:c}")
                            .Title("UNIT PRICE")
                            .Width(220);
                        columns.Bound(f => f.Quantity)
                            .Title("AMOUNT")
                            .Width(220)
                            .ClientFooterTemplate("Grand total:");
                        columns.Template(f => new { })
                            .Title("TOTAL")
                            .ClientTemplate("\\#=kendo.toString(GetOrderItemPrice(data), \"c\")\\#")
                            .ClientFooterTemplate("<span name='sum'></span>").Width(120);

                    })
                    .Events(e =>
                    {
                        e.DataBound("onOrderDetailsDataBound");
                        e.DetailInit("onDetailInit");
                        e.Edit("onOrderDetailsEdit");
                    })
                    .Selectable()
                    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true))
                    .Navigatable()
                    .ClientDetailTemplateId("Product_DetailTemplate")
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(detail => detail.OrderDetailID);
                        })
                        .Events(e => e.Error(errorEvent))
                        .Read("OrderDetails_Read", "OrderDetails", new { OrderID = "#=OrderID#" })
                        
                    ).ToClientTemplate()
                    )</text>);
            items.Add()
                .Text("MOVEMENT DETAILS")
                .Content(@<text>
                    <div class='shipping-details'>
                        <ul>
                            <li><label>Name:</label>#= ShipName #</li>
                            <li><label>OrderStatus:</label>#= ShipCountry #</li>
                            <li><label>City:</label>#= ShipCity #</li>
                            <li><label>Address:</label>#= ShipAddress #</li>
                            <li><label>Postal Code:</label>#= ShipPostalCode #</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </text>);
        })
                                                                        .ToClientTemplate()
        )
    </script>
```

and my controller :

```js
public ActionResult Orders_Approve([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, OrderViewModel order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var northwind = new NCashEntities())
                {
                    var entity = northwind.ORDERS.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ORDERID == order.OrderID);
                    if (entity == null)
                    {
                        string errorMessage = string.Format("Cannot update record with OrderID:{0} as it's not available.", order.OrderID);
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entity.CUSTOMERID = order.CustomerID;
                        entity.EMPLOYEEID = order.EmployeeID;
                        entity.ORDERDATE = order.OrderDate;
                        entity.SHIPCOUNTRY = "Approved";
                        entity.SHIPVIA = order.ShipVia;
                        entity.SHIPPEDDATE = order.ShippedDate;
                        entity.SHIPNAME = order.ShipName;
                        entity.SHIPADDRESS = order.ShipAddress;
                        entity.SHIPCITY = order.ShipCity;
                        entity.SHIPPOSTALCODE = order.ShipPostalCode;

                        northwind.ORDERS.Attach(entity);
                        northwind.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        northwind.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(new[] { order }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to save something back if nothing has changed? Do you want this to be the default behaviour for all edits for this grid?

Comment: Thanks David, Look at it this way ...its like an approve order view. the approve will not change anything on the order. But the status will be changed to "Approved" in the controller.  This is the default behaviour of all edits for this particular grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is one way of potentially doing what you want to do.

If you add an event handler to the edit event by adding

this to your grid (adding to the existing event you have for error)

```
e.Edit("onEdit");
```

then adding a javascript function like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
 e.model.dirty= true;
}
```

this should set the dirty flag for you and allow you to update the model.

Although this can be done. I would personally think you would be better binding this "approve" action to a button or making it selectable. Just in case someone accidently approves one of your orders when you don't want it to be approved. But that is just the way I would think about this type of "business logic".

Any issues let me know and I will adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: I added .Events(e => {
                e.Error(@<text>
                    function (e) {
                    onError(e, "orders");
                    }
                </text>);
                e.Edit("onEdit");
                })   but  it errors out 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DataSourceEventBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Edit' and no extension...."     .If add it the .Events(e =>
            {
                e.DataBound("onDataBound");
               e.Edit("onEdit"); 
            })    ..... this works but nothing changes. the event is not hit when i debug the js.

Comment: Hi @Laolu I have fixed my code now. You just need to set `e.model.dirty` rather than isDirty. I have tested this out with a sample project and the update call was ran as expected.

Comment: @Laolu not a problem. Glad I could help.